# Creating a chart in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mschart

I am working on a project and need to add an additional image using the asp:chart control. Unfortunately, I've never had to use this control before and it's a bit complex to use, so I need some help.

Basically, I need to create a stacked Column chart with two legends and two columns. The first column is "income" and stacks three values. (Wages, interest and other.) The second column is "expenses" and stacks two values. (Mortgage, Other.) Each value has it's own value.
The legend for income should be on the left, the column for expenses to the right. These legends should display the texts and values for it's related value plus a 'Total' label with value.

For this task, I only have to deal with 5 values over two columns but the asp:chart control is huge and I'm drowning in all it's options. And they want it ready yesterday, so no pressure. It's already overdue... :-)

No, it's not homework. If it was, I would have practical documentation and the additional how-to information. Since my Boss expects me to add this, he just gave me absolutely no information to work with, except for the code which already contains several other charts, none of them like this one and all done by previous victims who each used their own coding style. Basically, the project code is a huge mess so useless as documentation. (And amazingly it works, as long as I only use asp:chart for these graphics.)

The biggest problem I'm having is stacking the values correctly. Since I have two columns and 3 values, it could be solved with three series, each with points for column 1 and 2. Unfortunately, this puts income and expense in the same label, which is not what I want.
If I make it 5 series, for every value one point, then the second column doesn't start at the right height. So that won't work either.

Comment: I ended up just writing my own code to create a bitmap, draw the columns by code and then return it as PNG file. This provided the exact layout that was desired, which would have taken a lot more time if I had to use the chart component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Samples for Chart Control from msdn which give you complete in depth knowledge of how to use them

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

For learning see these blogs as well

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, examples of StackedColumns are scarse

Comment: Well, the examples showed that it's a lot of work to get working and a lot of details are added that I don't want in my chart. Drawing the chart in code was easier so I've chosen that option.